what is the most economical way to design a small & simple box?
Would someone recommend to me how I can create my own design for a small & simple case that holds a microcontroller and 9 volt battery with a 3.55 mm jack? It would have to be small enough to be held in the hand.
The design would have to be in a format ready to print. Is there an online service that allows me to create the design myself, or is there a company you can recommend to me that would create the design for me?

Recommendations aren't allowed unfortunately. Have you searched on Thingiverse?

I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping/service recommendation

As an alternative to Fred's excellent suggestion, you could use Fusion 360 and follow this excellent YouTube course from Paul McWhorter, All New Fusion 360 for 3D Printing for Absolute Beginners1.
It was so good that I have actually watched it twice (from start to end). It might take a while but totally worth it (even if you already know and/or work with other 3D CAD packages).
Becoming proficient (and self sufficient) in using 3D CAD software/tools will save you both time and money in the long run, as well as providing a sense of satisfaction.

1 There is also an earlier course, Learn Fusion 360 or Die Trying LESSON 1: Introduction tutorial for Absolute Beginners
.

If this question were to be posted in the SE for software recommendations, one might reply with the suggestion to use Autodesk's Tinkercad, a free browser based program for designing 3D models. The options for exporting the created items are formatted directly for 3D printing. There are many video tutorials for getting started with this program.
